# How to debug "Choreographer: Skipped X frames"

Tags: java, android, optimization, logcat

I always try to keep the main thread running as smooth as possible but sometimes I just don't succeed.

When this happens I get the following error message in my logcat:

> Choreographer: Skipped X frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I would like to know how to debug this error in general. 
I currently just do a 'Log.d()' after every function to see which function takes too much time. But I mean, a log after every function just takes way too long to debug.

Hope you guys can help!